# WebGPU Tools for Debugging

Tags: opengl, gpu

Is there any debugging tools for WebGPU?

Something like RenderDoc app that I can see the buffers and frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WebGPU Recorder**

> WebGPU Recorder is a debugging tool for WebGPU.
>
> It is a playback recorder, designed to capture all WebGPU commands and
> data, with the ability to play back the commands to recreate the
> render.
>
> It captures all WebGPU commands, buffers, and textures, over a given
> number of frames. It will then generate an HTML file containing
> javascript with all of the WebGPU commands recorded. This generated
> HTML file can be opened in the browser to play back the recording.
>
> This can be used to diagnose issues with WebGPU rendering by
> eliminating everything but the raw WebGPU commands. This is also very
> helpful for submitting self-contained reproduction examples for bug
> reports.
>
> https://github.com/brendan-duncan/webgpu_recorder

Comment: It sounds a great tools. I m going to test it. Thank you!